# How consistent is PHP hrtime()?

Tags: php

I'm currently using `hrtime()` in one of my project, a chat system (still in development stage).

On each message sent, I store the `hrtime(true)` value along with the message into database.

So recipient will request for new messages based on last message hrtime stored in app localStorage.
like for example:  `select*from messages_table where message_hrtime>$last_hrtime and message_to=$me`

It has been working alright until today, thrn I noticed new messages
`hrtime(true)` value inserted into DB decreased which make new messages not to be received.

[image: Notice the column message_hrtime decreased from id 35]

Notice the column message_hrtime decreased on id 35

And according to this article
https://thephp.cc/articles/high-resolution-monotonic-timer, that hrtime() is ever increasing.

Now confused if the `hrtime(true)` is consistent.

PHP 7.3

Comment: Are you clear on what [`HRTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php) is? It seems like maybe you just want to be using [`microtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) instead of a measurement from an arbitrary point in time?

Comment: HRTime counts from an arbitrary point in time, eg: when the system was last booted. You should only use it within the scope of a single execution as it is effectively meaningless otherwise. You almost certainly want to be using something derived from a `microtime()` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) provides "the current Unix timestamp with microseconds", The [HRTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php) class, or High resolution timing, "Returns the system's high resolution time, counted from an **arbitrary** point in time. The delivered timestamp is monotonic and can not be adjusted.".

That means HRTime is independent of server time. You can't depend on this across servers or even across restarts of a server. I wouldn't trust it across code execution. Use the database timestamp or simply switch to use PHP's `microtime`.

HRTime has interesting application as a precise stop watch as shown here on php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/hrtime.example.basic.php

```
<?php

$c = new HRTime\StopWatch;

$c->start();
/* measure this code block execution */
for ($i = 0; $i < 1024*1024; $i++);
$c->stop();
$elapsed0 = $c->getLastElapsedTime(HRTime\Unit::NANOSECOND);

/* measurement is not running here*/
for ($i = 0; $i < 1024*1024; $i++);

$c->start();
/* measure this code block execution */
for ($i = 0; $i < 1024*1024; $i++);
$c->stop();
$elapsed1 = $c->getLastElapsedTime(HRTime\Unit::NANOSECOND);

$elapsed_total = $c->getElapsedTime(HRTime\Unit::NANOSECOND);
```

Comment: Why can't you have two messages at the same time? Sounds perfectly feasible. How precise do you want to get? Leverage the database, one is inserted before the other, use a timestamp and auto generated ID if you want to break a tie. eg.  combination of  ORDER BY id DESC with timestamp constraint or second order by col.

Comment: I got that. One more question on microtime, if it's used inside a for loop, is there chance that i can have same microtime value? which is exactly what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The answer is probably yes. I would not make the "received" timestamp a unique column in the database.  I can't speak to your architecture but two people can usually "talk" at once. Question of reasonable level of precision. Sounds like earlier comment made sense? Cheers.